# Google Protobuf undefined method msgclass' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, logstash, protocol-buffers

I use google protobuf in the logstash input,Start error when running logstash。

> ./bin/logstash -f logstash.conf -r

the error is:

```
[ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exceptio n=>"NoMethodError", :message=>"undefined method msgclass' for nil:NilClass", :backtrace=>["/home/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-codec-pr otobuf-1.1.0/lib/logstash/codecs/protobuf.rb:101:inregister'", "/home/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/codecs/base.rb:20:in initialize'", "/home/logs tash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/plugin_factory.rb:97:inplugin'", "/home/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:110:in plugin'", "(eval) :8:in'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:994:in eval'", "/home/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:82:ininitialize'", "/home/logstash/log stash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:167:in initialize'", "/home/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:inexecute'", "/home/log stash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:305:in `block in converge_state'"]}
```

logstash.conf is setting:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => false
    codec => protobuf {
      class_name => ["Elk.ElkData"]
      include_path => ["/home/logstash/test_code/elk.pb.rb"]
      protobuf_version => 3
    }
    type => "protobuf"
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

the **'register'** in the 'logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-codec-protobuf-1.1.0/lib/logstash/codecs/protobuf.rb' is:

```
def register
  @metainfo_messageclasses = {}
  @metainfo_enumclasses = {}
  @metainfo_pb2_enumlist = []
  include_path.each { |path| load_protobuf_definition(path) }
  if @protobuf_version == 3
    @pb_builder = Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.lookup(class_name).msgclass
  else
    @pb_builder = pb2_create_instance(class_name)
  end
end
```

*Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.lookup(class_name).msgclass*

logstash version is 6.3.0, protoc version is 3.6.1, ruby-protoc version is 1.6.1,
Elk community question connection is as follows：
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-uses-protobuf-running-error-nomethoderror-message-undefined-method-msgclass-for-nil-nilclass/144806?u=sun_changlong

Is it my environmental factor or the protobuf version? Can be used in the protobuf 2 environment.*Welcome to leave valuable suggestions*

Comment: Any news on this?